# LESS.js - Error msg "failed to save"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am in the middle of a project and this morning the less JS file (I am currently using the "less.min.js" JS file for the browser (Chrome) states in the console "failed to save". This is causing my "scripts.js" file to fail **when functions are** in the "$(window).load()". Interesting enough, however, Bootstrap is still working, as is my LESS CSS (all my styles are on the page as it should be).

I also have Web Essestials installed, and is set to auto-compile on save (this setting was set previous to the error).

```
 <title>@title</title>
<link href="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less")" rel="stylesheet/less">
<link href="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Content/styles.less")" rel="stylesheet/less" />
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/modernizr.custom.js")"></script>
<script src="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/less.min.js")"></script>
@*TODO: pre-compile less and remove script*@
<script src="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/json2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Fingerprint.Tag("/Scripts/scripts.js")"></script>
```

I have checked my security settings for IIS and they seem to be fine (once again, these are all the same settings as I was using yesterday prior to the error).

```
 XHR finished loading: GET "http://local.lenders-one.com/Content/bootstrap/v-635549376660341373/bootstrap.less".
less.js:408 
    XHR finished loading: GET "http://local.lenders-one.com/Content/v-635556102777513301/styles.less".
less.js:771 
    failed to save - less.js:771
```

The "Fingerprint" class is a utility class that applies fake folders for file caching. I removed the utility class from the javascript/LESS files and I was still receiving the error.

I am using LESS v2.0.0 - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could this be part of it?  The Less.js browser script currently won’t work if you’re using Chrome and the path to your page starts with “file:///” due to a known Chrome issue.  It doesn't look like the issue, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: Yeah I checked on this, however I brought it up in FF and IE and same issue occurs.

Comment: Could it be something in the `.less` file, something in `styles.less`, that is causing the issue?  I'd start by stripping it down to bare minimum style and let it compile that ... see where the issue actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "failed to save" is not very descriptive, but this error is send when less.js fail to write the compiled CSS code to local storage. (in your case possible because the path is not right) (see: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less-browser/cache.js).

> Interesting enough, however, Bootstrap is still working, as is my LESS CSS (all my styles are >on the page as it should be).

Although caching fails the compiled code will be send to the browser.

> (once again, these are all the same settings as I was using yesterday prior to the error).

setting `less.env` to `development` also disable the caching and so the error.

Comment: You were quite right w/ the caching - as it was my "Fingerprint" class which was adding the "fake" folder structure where the CSS files were being compiled. This site as well led me to figure out the solution as well.  [http://orangescale.net/blog/log/2012/11/twitter-bootstrap-less-css-and-caching-problem/](http://orangescale.net/blog/log/2012/11/twitter-bootstrap-less-css-and-caching-problem/)